# Jquery function not working with parameter values

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

***Question background:***

I'm attempting to display the contents of an array in a table on my MVC sites view.

***The issue:***

I have a JQuery 'AddRow' function which dynamically adds rows to the tables based on however many 'CartItems' are in the passed list from the Controller for the 'foreach' to iterate round.

Currently when I pass the the parameters to 'AddRow' **no rows** are being added to the table. If I supply no parameters and supply dummy table data it does add.

**Here's the code:**

```
<table id="Table1" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Unit Price</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

var AddRows = function (productName,productPrice,productQty)
{
     var html = '<tr>'
                '<td>'+productName.toString+'</td>' +
                '<td>'+productPrice.toString+'</td>' +
                '<td>'+productQty.toString+'</td>' +
                '</tr>'
     $(html).appendTo($("#Table1"))
};
```

```
@foreach (var cartItem in (List<LoginTest.Models.CartItem>)ViewBag.Data)
{
<script>
    AddRows(@cartItem.CartItemName, @cartItem.CartItemPrice, @cartItem.CartItemQty)
</script>
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `.toString()` method? or is there something called `.toString` ?

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Comment: @kums the 'CartItemName, CartItemPrice and CartItemQty' properites are all of type string. I've also tried setting 'ToString()' on these properties along with setting '.toString' on the variables in the 'AddRows' function. Neither seem to work.

Comment: Remove `.toString` is not required while rendering the values in html. also Note: `toString` is native js `function` if you want to use it the call the function like `.toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem once, It was something to do with JavaScript not liking the Razor Objects:

I fixed it like this:

```
@foreach (var cartItem in (List<LoginTest.Models.CartItem>)ViewBag.Data)
{
<script>

var cartItemName = '@cartItem.CartItemName';
var cartItemPrice = '@cartItem.CartItemPrice';
var cartItemCartItemQty = '@cartItem.CartItemQty';

    AddRows(cartItemName , cartItemPrice , cartItemCartItemQty )
</script>
}
```

Then you don't need toString()

```
var AddRows = function (productName,productPrice,productQty)
{
     var $html = $('<tr>'
                '<td>'+productName+'</td>' +
                '<td>'+productPrice+'</td>' +
                '<td>'+productQty+'</td>' +
                '</tr>');
     //$(html).appendTo($("#Table1"));

    $('#Table1 > tbody:last').append($html);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this and still have the same issue.

Comment: See my Edit to jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use document ready function because your AddRows function is executed before load jQuery

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       @foreach (var cartItem in (List<LoginTest.Models.CartItem>)ViewBag.Data)
       {
           AddRows('@cartItem.CartItemName', '@cartItem.CartItemPrice', '@cartItem.CartItemQty' );
       } 
    }); 
</script>


var AddRows = function (productName,productPrice,productQty)
{
     var html = '<tr>'
                '<td>'+productName+'</td>' +
                '<td>'+productPrice+'</td>' +
                '<td>'+productQty+'</td>' +
                '</tr>'
     $(html).appendTo($("#Table1"))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong syntax for the `toString()` method. Use it as follows

`number.toString(radix)`

With radix being an often unused, optional parameter used to set the base for representing the number.